# Rails: How do I set up a collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to set up a search / filter using collection_select.

Firstly: This works. It lists all cases for employee with `id = 15`.

```
<%= form_tag(cases_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :param_e, 15 %>
  <%= submit_tag "Filter", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

But what I want is a `collection_select`, so I can list cases for any employee.

```
<%= form_tag(cases_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= collection_select( :x, :y, Employee.all, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => false }) %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :param_e, :z %>
  <%= submit_tag "Filter", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

This shows the `collection_select` with all the employees in a drop-down.

How to I connect-up the collection_select?

Comment: `select_tag :param_e, options_from_collection_for_select(Employee.all, :id, :name)` instead of the `collection_select` helper

Comment: the `collection_select` helper is not suitable for things like this, because it expects an object and an accessor as first 2 arguments

Comment: should I be using: select ?

Comment: used: select_tag :param_e, options_from_collection_for_select(Employee.all, :id, :name) as per comment above and it worked.

Comment: @GraemeJensz what's the problem with `collection_select` ?